# How to wait for edges in always block?

Tags: verilog, fpga, quartus

I am trying to write something like this:

```
always@(posedge bus_start)
begin
    @(posedge scl) buffer[7] = sda;
    @(posedge scl) buffer[6] = sda;
    @(posedge scl) buffer[5] = sda;
    @(posedge scl) buffer[4] = sda;
    @(posedge scl) buffer[3] = sda;
    @(posedge scl) buffer[2] = sda;
    @(posedge scl) buffer[1] = sda;
    @(posedge scl) buffer[0] = sda;
end
```

But it is not synthesizable according to the error I got.

I may use FSM to solve this, but that could make it complicated, is there any way to make it synthesizable?

Comment: No. This is high-level, behavioural Verilog. It would make a fine reference model for a testbench, but is not nearly detailed enough to be synthesisable. The _level of abstraction_ (level of detail) at which you need to write synthesisable code is called RTL (Register Transfer Level), in which you almost manually decide where the flip-flops are and the synthesiser fills in the combinational logic. For this I2C interface, you'll need a shift-register, you'll need an FSM, you'll probably need a counter. See [my company's website](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/verilog_designers_guide/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to capture data from an I2C interface.
Here is a simple solution for capturing 8 bits of data from `sda` and storing that into a register called `buffer`.

```
// starts on rising edge of scl or bus_start
always@(posedge bus_start or posedge scl) 
begin
    buffer[0] <= sda; // loads sda into the lowest bit of buffer
    buffer[7:1] <= buffer[6:0]; // shifts the lower 6 bits one to
                                // the left, acting as a shift register
end
```

More information about I2C in verilog can be found [here](http://www.fpga4fun.com/I2C_2.html)
In addition, a basic I2C slave can be found [here](http://opencores.org/project,i2cslave) (you must register and login to view the source code).

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough information.

Answer from @Krabby127 is also not synthesisable.

I think you have a lot of more work to do. You should to learn the difference between Verilog and C,first. RTL code is to describe the hardware in FPGA.So the concept of synthesisable is very important for you.

And you have to take care of debounce of I2C signal.Take care of tristate signal.
After all I suggest you to get some I2C project from opencores.org to study.
Forgive my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

I2C slaves mostly use a sampling clock other than SCL. I don't mean that it's impossible otherwise, but the common practice is to use a faster clock for sampling SCL and SDA signals.

I definitely recommend to start the design with the below ports at minimum. Since SDA is a tristate signal, I also recommend not to deal with it at this stage. You can assume that it's done out of your module and can continue with separate input and output ports.

```
input  clk;     // system clock
input  rst;     // system reset

input  scl;     // i2c clock
input  sda_in;  // i2c input data
output sda_out; // i2c output data
```

To be honest, I2C is not a good choice to learn an HDL (Verilog/SV/VHDL) and digital design. It will bring some complex issues.